# Have an alternate background if the background image doesnt load

Tags: html, css

I currently have an image that covers some screen resolutions, but if the screen resolution is bigger than the image, it will be white for each pixel its bigger, so instead of that ugly white, I want a color behind that background image so it wont look ugly. My current code is just an img tag for the background and the css scales it up to 100% but if the screen res is larger than the image res, it will create problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Comment: you need to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you're using an img tag as your background image, instead of setting a div to have it's background as that image? Because you can do this with css fairly easily.

```
.background-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(your_image_url) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
```

Where the .background-div would be in place of your img... This could also be the `body` of the document, or whatever. It's just a container div that covers the whole background.

The background then has a fallback colour of #e3e3e3, and `background-size: cover` means that it will always scale the image to fill the screen, so you won't see that colour. 
You could also use `contain` instead, which would make the image scale how you're expecting, and show the background colour where the image doesn't reach.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me, i had the non-working fallback set as "background: green;" but apparently it was "background-color: green;" that would work, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent div of your image and add a stylesheet attribute.

It will look something like this

```
<div class="parent" style="background-color: #000000;height: 100%;width: 100%;">
<img src="your image url" class="image" alt="alt" title="your title"/>
</div>
```

the attr style="background-color: #000000;" will give the div a black background color.

You can also set the background color by its classname insde you style.css file. Or what ever you named the file.

```
.parent {
     background: #000;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}

.parent img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

I hope this is the awnser your searching for. If not, provide some more details. Maybe show the structure of your current code.